# Drawing auxiliary lines in tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

In latex, how do I draw an auxiliary line, a line that is partitioned into many little lines, from one point to another point with tikz?

I know how to use regular lines, but not auxiliary.

Comment: This question may be better suited for [TeX and LaTeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `rnd`?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[domain=0:1] (\x,rnd*0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wiggly TikZ-line via rnd]

Comment: is it possible to turn this into an arrow as well? So let this originate from point (a) to point (b)?